# Given an integer n, how to find (2^x) % 1000000007, where x = binary representation of n now considered base 10.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Suppose we are given n = 4.
Now its binary is 100. we take x as 100 and we want to compute (2^100) % 1000000007.
I know the modular exponentiation algorithm but here n <= 600000. This means the bit representation of n may have upto 20 digits which overflows the capacity of even long long integer(10^18).
Is there some trick which can be worked out...may be some discrete maths concept..Please help.

Answer (score 0):

a ^ b % N = ((a % N) ^ b) % N

In other words you can take the modulo any time you want in the exponentiation, and work with numbers < N

example :

```
2^6 % 10
2^3 = 8
2^4 = 16 = 6 % 10
2^5 = 2^4 * 2 = 6 * 2 = 12 = 2 % 10 
2^6 = 2^5 * 2 = 2 * 2 = 4 % 10
```

Apply this principle to fast exponentiation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: I think you are not following what the question is....we are given n(range is <= 600000)...first we have to convert this to its binary representation...then we consider that binary represented number as a base 10 number and compute 2 ^ (this base 10 considered number) % 1000000007.

Comment: i mean if n = 10. then its binary representation is 1010 base 2...We consider this as base 10 ie..One thousand ten..now we compute 2^1010...the problem is since binary representation of 600000 has 20 digits it cannot be contained in any data type...Plus it had to be done very fastly...

Comment: I followed your question and my answer gives you keys. I guess you can convert n to binary and take the decimal number out of it by yourself. Let's call this N.
Then do what I say, taking the modulo in your calculus every time it is possible to keep numbers low. To speed up the process use my link